# UDP winsock server c++ with blocking

Tags: c++, network-programming, udp, server, winsock

I am trying to program a udp client and server that will return the offset between the ntp time and boxtime. I cannot get my server to correctly receive data. I am testing it with Microsoft Unit tests, and when I try and test the server and client the test actually fails. If I run the test I just get the error message:

> "The active Test Run was aborted because the execution process exited unexpectedly. To investigate further, enable local crash dumps either at the machine level or for process vstest.executionengine.x86.exe. Go to more details: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=232477"

If I debug I find that recvfrom function in the server returns 0, so it just exits.

Here is my code for the server:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include "NtpServer.h"
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <winsock.h>
#include <errno.h>


using std::chrono::system_clock;

namespace ntp
{


struct sockaddr_in server;
struct sockaddr_storage client;



//constructor to create ntp server
 NtpServer::NtpServer(u_short portnum, const std::chrono::nanoseconds                 desiredOffset) : portnum(0), client_length(0), bytes_received(0), current_time(0), desiredOffset(0)
{

    WSADATA wsaData;

    int iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);

    if (iResult != 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "Could not open Windows connection." << std::endl; 
        exit(0);
    }

    memset((void *)&server, '\0', sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(portnum);
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);


    sd = WSASocket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 17, NULL, 0, NULL);

    if (sd == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        std::cerr << "Could not create socket." << std::endl;
        WSACleanup();
        exit(0);
    }



if (bind(sd, reinterpret_cast<SOCKADDR *>(&server),
        sizeof(server)) == -1)
    {
        std::cerr << "Could not bind name to socket" << std::endl;
        closesocket(sd);
        WSACleanup();
        exit(0);
    }



    getResult(desiredOffset);
}

NtpServer::~NtpServer()
{
    closesocket(sd);
    WSACleanup();

}   

void NtpServer::getResult(const std::chrono::nanoseconds desiredOffset)
{
    ntp_data ntpData = ntp_data();

    //set up timeout with blocking
    fd_set fds;
    int n;
    struct timeval tv;
    FD_ZERO(&fds);
    FD_SET(sd, &fds);
    tv.tv_sec = 10;  // 10 Secs Timeout 
    tv.tv_usec = 0;
    n = select(sd, &fds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
    if (n == 0)
    {
        exit(0);
    }

    while (1)
    {
        //client_length = sizeof(client); 
        int len = (int)sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

        /* Receive bytes from client */
        bytes_received = recvfrom(sd, sendBuffer, NTP_PACKET_MAX, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&client, &len);

        if (bytes_received == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            std::cerr << "Could not receive datagram." << std::endl;
            closesocket(sd);
            WSACleanup();
            exit(0);
        }
        if (bytes_received < NTP_PACKET_MIN)
        {
            continue; 
        }



        /* Check for time request */
        if (strcmp(readBuffer, "GET TIME\r\n") == 0)
        {
            /* Get current time */
            system_clock::time_point now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
            auto timepointoffset = (now + desiredOffset).time_since_epoch();
            double current_value = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double>>(timepointoffset).count();

            unpack_ntp(&ntpData, (unsigned char *)readBuffer, bytes_received);
            make_packet(&ntpData, NTP_CLIENT, current_value);
            pack_ntp((unsigned char *)sendBuffer, NTP_PACKET_MIN, &ntpData);


            /* Send data back */
            if (sendto(sd, sendBuffer,
                (int)sizeof(sendBuffer), 0,
                (struct sockaddr *)&client, client_length) !=
                (int)sizeof(current_time))
            {
                std::cerr << "Error sending datagram." << std::endl;
                closesocket(sd);
                WSACleanup();
                exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
    closesocket(sd);
    WSACleanup();

}



}
```

Edit: I changed the way I did the timeout with a select statement, and recvfrom "if" statements.

Comment: A UDP receive should never return zero. Are you sure you've observed the symptoms correctly?

Comment: @EJP - To be clear, a UDP receive *can* return zero if the other side sends a zero byte datagram.

Comment: Elijah -- How/where is `sendBuffer` defined?

Comment: @keithmo Ah yes of course, silly of me.

Comment: @keithmo sendBuffer is defined in the .h file as a char array of size "NTP_PACKET_MIN" which is defined as 48.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bytes_received = recvfrom(sd, sendBuffer, NTP_PACKET_MAX, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&client, &client_length);

if (bytes_received < NTP_PACKET_MIN)
{
    std::cerr << "Could not receive datagram." << std::endl;
    closesocket(sd);
    WSACleanup();
    exit(0);
}
```

Should be:

```
bytes_received = recvfrom(sd, sendBuffer, NTP_PACKET_MAX, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&client, &client_length);

if (bytes_received == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    int err = WSAGetLastError();

    // Handle WSAETIMEDOUT here if necessary

    std::cerr << "Could not receive datagram, error: " << err << std::endl;
    closesocket(sd);
    WSACleanup();
    exit(0);
}

if (bytes_received < NTP_PACKET_MIN)
{
    // print/log a warning here
    continue;
}
```

This aborts the receive loop if a call to `recvfrom()` fails, but simply ignores invalid packets (those less than the minimum length).

Another issue:

```
unpack_ntp(&ntpData, (unsigned char *)readBuffer, bytes_received);
make_packet(&ntpData, NTP_CLIENT, current_value);
pack_ntp((unsigned char *)sendBuffer, NTP_PACKET_MIN, &ntpData);

/* Send data back */
if (sendto(sd, sendBuffer,
    (int)sizeof(sendBuffer), 0,
    (struct sockaddr *)&client, client_length) != (int)sizeof(current_time))
{
    std::cerr << "Error sending datagram." << std::endl;
    closesocket(sd);
    WSACleanup();
    exit(0);
}
```

You're sending the entire `sendBuffer`; you should probably send only the size of the NTP packet. (Hopefully `pack_ntp` returns the packet size and you can use that). Also, you're comparing the sent size with `sizeof(current_time)` which makes zero sense. You should compare against the size of the buffer sent.

There are other minor issues, but these are the big ones that jump out.

Comment: So when you say compare against the size of the buffer sent, do you mean the size of "sendBuffer"? In that case didn't I already do that in the 3rd argument of the sendto function?

Comment: Now that I think about it, you should just compare the return value from `sendto()` with SOCKET_ERROR. `sendto()` on a UDP socket will either send the complete datagram or it will fail (it will never send a partial datagram).

Comment: Ok thank you for the help so far. So far I still have the same issue, where my select statement is returning zero and exiting. So my code never actually reaches recvfrom. I'm just not sure is this because the server isn't receiving anything from the client, or if my server isn't running correctly.

Comment: Are you calling `select()` with a non-zero timeout (similar to the SO_RCVTIMEO you used before)? If so, `select()`returns 0 to indicate no network events happened before the timeout expired.

Comment: Yes, I you're correct, so no network event have happened. I am going to edit again to show some changes I did in code.

Answer (score 1):

You have this line of code:

```
setsockopt(sd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char *)&tv, sizeof(struct timeval));
```

If the 10 second timeout elapses because no data was received, `recvfrom()` will return -1 and `WSAGetLastError()` will return 10060.  Your code is exiting in that situation:

```
bytes_received = recvfrom(sd, sendBuffer, NTP_PACKET_MAX, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&client, &len);

if (bytes_received == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    std::cerr << "Could not receive datagram." << std::endl;
    closesocket(sd);
    WSACleanup();
    exit(0); // <-- here
}
```

Even if `select()` times out, you are exiting as well:

```
n = select(sd, &fds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
if (n == 0)
{
    exit(0); // <-- here
}
```

Make sure there is another application actually sending data to your UDP app.

Comment: I actually changed that code, and replaced it with a select function. There shouldn't be anything else sending data to my UDP app.

Comment: @Elijah, if you expect to receive data in the test, somebody has to send it. Otherwise the select will also have a timeout and the socket will not have data (not ready for reading). Otherwise you need to change the expected result of your test.

Comment: Oh I misunderstood, I have a client that should be sending data.

Comment: @rodolk: Your answer is asking a question. That should have been posted as a comment instead. In any case, if a blocking `recvfrom()` times out due to `SO_RCVTIMEO`, it does not return 0, like you claim. It returns -1 (`SOCKET_ERROR`) and `WSAGetLastError()` will then return 10060 (`WSAETIMEDOUT`). But the end effect is the same, since the code is bailing out when `recvfrom()` returns anything `< NTP_PACKET_MIN`, which includes both 0 and -1.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, you are right, and I upvoted your comment. I edited my response to indicate it returns -1. A mistake. Regarding the question, it's important considering there is a timeout.

Comment: @rodolk: I understand that, but prompting the OP for more information belongs in comments, not in the answer itself.  I have reworked your answer to state facts, not ask questions.